# How would one create different environments in Commercetools?

Tags: cloud, microservices, cicd, commercetools

I am trying to set up Commercetools with a CI/CD pipeline. It is my first time working with microservices and cloud architectures.

With a monolithic code base you can have development, QA and production environments - how would one go about this with Commercetools? Would you setup two/three projects? Should the projects share the same microservices or would you set up multiple of those as well? If not, then I suppose you would do end-to-end testing on production, that can't be right?

*I am not interested in how to setup microservices, I am interested in how to set up the project that performs changes to the Commercetools API.*

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would typically set up separate projects for production, development and staging. How you set up the extended behaviour of extensions, SDKs and custom applications is up to you. Extensions are usually connected to the projects via the project key and custom applications can be used by multiple projects of one organisation for example.

Answer (score 0):

Go to profile icon and -> select manage projects
Create project and select organisation u want to create.
Now 2 projects will create in different environment.
Top right side you can change environment you want to work.